# Remote control server dialing out to viewer?

Tags: windows, remote

I'm looking for a remote control application that satisfies the following requirements:

- the server (ie. the application
  running on the customer's PC I need
  to support) dials out to connect to
  the client running on my support PC
  and waiting for incoming connections.
  No port-mapping on the customer's
  firewall required
- the server must be single EXE (no setup software setup required)
- ideally, one application for both XP and Vista
- Direct connection between server and client: I don't want to rely on some web service like CoPilot to act as repeater
- Either open-source or affordable

UltraVNC works fine on XP but doesn't run OK on Vista (screen lags, connection breaks). The new project, PCHelpWare, doesn't run that well either. And the UVNC site is a mess.

Does someone know of an application that satisfies these requirements?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a modem based solution, or a web based solution?

For a web based solution to work like this you'd need to have major holes in your companies firewall setup to allow access.

The company I work for uses [logmeinrescue.com](http://www.logmeinrescue.com) so that we can access the customers desktop.  We simply have them go to logmein123.com and they enter a 6 digit pin number that the customer service rep gives them.  The rep is then able to see the customers desktop via a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

What about the built-in Remote Assistance application?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip. I looks like [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) is almost what I was looking for (both hosts connect out through TCP80 to TeamViewer's servers which act as repeaters).